# How to add a list in a list as an element?

Tags: list, append, common-lisp

For demonstration purpose,

I have list with has a list:

```
 > (setf x (list '(1 2 1) '(4 5 4)))
 ((1 2 1) (4 5 4))
 > (length x)
 2
```

I want to add a new list '(2 3 2) to it. The **append** function:

```
 > (append '(2 3 2) x)
 (2 3 2 (1 2 1) (4 5 4))

 > (length (append '(2 3 2) x))
 5
```

isn't really doing what I want.

What I want is to add '(2 3 2) like this:

```
((8 7 8) (1 2 1) (4 5 4))
```

so that the length is  3.

So far, I haven't seen any example or ways to do what I want. Is there a built-in function or effective way of doing this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[APPEND](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_append.htm#append) is not a destructive function, which is what you are asking for. What APPEND does is allocate a new list, which it then returns.

What you can do to achieve your goals is:

`(setf x (append '((...)) x))  ;;appends the quoted list to x`

There is also the function [NCONC](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_nconc.htm), which adjusts pointers destructively.

For your meditations, I present example work:

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *x* nil)
*X*
CL-USER> (setf *x* '((1 2 3) (4 5 6)))
((1 2 3) (4 5 6))
CL-USER> (append *x* '(10 11 12))
((1 2 3) (4 5 6) 10 11 12)
CL-USER> (append *x* '((10 11 12)))
((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (10 11 12))
CL-USER> (setf *x* (append *x* '((10 11 12))))
((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (10 11 12))
CL-USER> *x*
((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (10 11 12))
CL-USER>
```

Comment: That was quick! I never thought of such idea.
And thanks for explanation about destructive and non-destructive functions with explanation. Helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

`APPEND` appends lists. If you have a list of two sublists `((1 2 1) (4 5 4))` and you want to append another list of one sublist `((2 3 2))` in front of it.

```
CL-USER 99 > (append '((2 3 2)) '((1 2 1) (4 5 4)))
((2 3 2) (1 2 1) (4 5 4))
```

or use this, if you want to add one item in front of the list:

```
CL-USER 98 > (cons '(2 3 2) '((1 2 1) (4 5 4)))
((2 3 2) (1 2 1) (4 5 4))
```